# The import com.google cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, api, google-calendar-api

I am just trying out the Google calendar APIs using rest calls. I do not intend to make an android app out of it right now. I followed the steps mentioned in https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/setup and got stuck when I tried importing. 
Steps I followed :
1. Made a console app project in Eclipse.
2. Made a java app project - JRE 1.8.0_25
3. Downloaded the zips from mentioned location in the calendar setup description.
4. In java build path in eclipse, I created 4 libraries(user) and in native library location added path to the unzipped lib folders.
5. made imports -

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.*;
```

and got the error : 
The import com.google cannot be resolved

I tried to go over all the previously asked questions - nothing helped.

Comment: "Native library location" is the wrong place to add the folders - a native library is one not written in Java.

Comment: Thanks @immibis. This was the problem. I tried to somehow put the jar files in library instead of adding them directly.

Answer (score 0):

These steps are not needed:

> 3. Downloaded the zips from mentioned location in the calendar setup description.
> 4. In java build path in eclipse, I created 4 libraries(user) and in native library location added path to the unzipped lib folders.

What you need to do instead is:

> download the core Java client library and the Google Calendar API
>   Java library .jar files and include them in your build path.

So no ZIP (but .jar), and simply add them to the build path (not as a native location but as Libraries/add JARs).

Comment: Perfect. I added external jar files and did not try to put those under a library - and it worked. Thank you!